# Vue3 Listen to event from dynamically created child component, $on replacement

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am creating a Vue component dynamically and I want to listen to an event that it emits. I know you can use the `@eventName` in the markup but I am creating the component using `createApp`.

```
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  this.$refs.login.appendChild(div);

  let props = {
     /** some props **/
  };

  createApp(Component, props,).mount(div);
```

This is how I create the `Component`. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56370274/3126835) works for my problem but it for Vue2 and the `$on` has been removed in Vue3.

How can I achieve this using Vue3?

Comment: One thing I can think of is to pass a callback as a prop and then execute that in the child component, but that seems a bit messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [render function (`h`)](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#h) to add the event handler. The second argument to `h` is an object whose keys beginning with `"on"` are treated as event handlers. For example, to add handlers for the `click` event and for an event named `my-event`:

```js
import { h } from 'vue'

const comp = h(Component, {
  onClick: e => console.log('click', e),
  onMyEvent: e => console.log('my-event', e),
})
createApp(comp, props).mount(div)
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/adding-event-listener-to-dynamically-created-component-forked-153b2?file=/src/App.vue:389-527)

If your project supports [JSX](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#jsx), the equivalent is:

```
const comp = <Component onClick={e => console.log('click', e)}
                        onMyEvent={e => console.log('my-event', e)} />
createApp(comp, props).mount(div)
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/adding-event-listener-to-dynamically-created-component-osjyr?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 1):

If your emitting from the child you can use this.

[Root Component Events#](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html)
Static event listeners can be added to the root component by passing them as props to createApp:

```
createApp(App, {
  // Listen for the 'expand' event
  onExpand() {
    console.log('expand')
  }
})
```